# Ideal Lowpass Filters

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-filters

I am a beginner to Digital Signal Processing. I took this course of DSP from Coursera in which I am stuck with this question. Since, I am new, please be descriptive. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have found the time based signal equation. Please refer this link to see the solution- 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HGlsXzGG3t-Ko3UDwFPkSmaIMW_vLXUR/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two lines of your solution are correct. But nothing after that is correct. (Those summation symbols should not be in your solution. Sequence y[n] is *NOT* equal to the sum of the samples in sequence y[n]!)

OK, for a half-band filter (whose impulse response is h[n]) here's what I have for the impulse response of your parallel-path network:

$$h_{parallel}[n] = h[n]+(-1)^nh[n]$$
$$= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}+(-1)^n\frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}$$
$$= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}[1+(-1)^n]$$
$$= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}[1+cos(n\pi)]$$
$$= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}+\frac{sin(n\pi/2)cos(n\pi)}{n\pi}.$$
$$\text{Using a trigonometric identity, we can write:}$$
$$h_{parallel}[n]= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}+\frac{sin(3n\pi/2)+sin(-n\pi/2)}{2n\pi}$$
$$= \frac{sin(n\pi/2)}{n\pi}+\frac{sin(3n\pi/2)-sin(n\pi/2)}{2n\pi}.$$
That's best I'm able to do at this point. If you evaluate that last equation for, say, n = -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0.001,1,2,3,4,5 you will see that your parallel network's impulse response is itself an impulse sample. (Compare what I've written here to the information in my first Answer above.)

Comment: Well, I understood where i made it wrong. Thankyou so much for your help. Keep helping people.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem, so it wouldn't help you too much if I gave you the answer. However, the answer to your problem is actually very educational. You need to model your network using software.

Sequence $w[n]$ will be the impulse response of the lowpass half-band filter. And when you multiply a half-band filter's impulse response by $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ you obtain a sequence whose spectrum is equal to a highpass filter frequency response whose cutoff frequency is also $\omega_c = \pi/2$. So the combined frequency response of your parallel two-path network will be the sum of the lowpass half-band and the highpass filters' frequency responses. Devansh, what will that combined frequency response look like? So now the final question is: What is the time-domain sequence (the impulse response) whose spectrum is the sum of the lowpass half-band and the highpass filters' frequency responses?

Comment: Regards Richard, 
Thanks for answering the question. I want to attach the solution that i made. I came up finding the final time dependent signal, which sums up to zero. So, in my opinion, answer should have been 0. But, it is wrong.
Please tell me where I am doing wrong. 
Here is the link-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HGlsXzGG3t-Ko3UDwFPkSmaIMW_vLXUR/view?usp=drivesdk
Thankyou.